# Do we have $(Ax,Ay) = (x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with any inner product when $A$ is an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be defined by $T(\boldsymbol{x})=A \boldsymbol{x}$, where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix. Is it true that for any inner product we have $(Ax,Ay) = (x,y)$? In other words, is $T$ an orthogonal transformation under any inner product?

Note: a transformation $\phi$ on a n-dimensional inner product space $V$ is orthogonal if
$$\forall \alpha, \beta \in V, (\phi(\alpha),\phi(\beta)) = (\alpha,\beta).$$

Comment: Have you tried to write an inner product as a quadratic form?

Comment: What is your definition of an orthogonal transformation?

Comment: @blamethelag Thanks for commenting. Do you mean $(x,y) = x^TAy$? I know little about this form of inner product. Do all inner product have this form?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for commenting. Added.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the "any" part of your question :) that is much more interesting.

Comment: You can start by noting that every bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented as a positive-definite symmetric matrix $B$. By this I mean that $\langle x, y \rangle = x^T B y$. This can always be done with $B_{i,j} = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$ (here $e_j$ are the standard basis vectors). To see that this identity holds, you can just expand $x,y$ in the basis and use bilinearity.

Comment: Now what kind of inner product can we have? For example $\langle (x,y), (u,v) \rangle = xu + 2yv$ defines a scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now what happens if you take $T(x,y) = (y,x)$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for your solution. Now I see that $\langle x, y\rangle=x^{T} B y$ is a very useful representation of bilinear form. The counterexample you give is the end of this problem. The conclusion is that the transformation $T(\boldsymbol{x})=A \boldsymbol{x}$, where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, has not to be an orthogonal transformation for any inner product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me convert my comment to an answer to get this question off the unanswered list. First, if you start with a scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, then we can always represent this in terms of a positive-definite matrix. Indeed. let $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n \}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and set $B=(\langle e_i, e_j \rangle)_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$. As the scalar product is symmetric, so is $B$. Furthermore, we have for $(a_i)_{i=1}^n\in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$
$$ 0< \langle \sum_{i=1} a_i e_i, \sum_{j=1}^n a_j e_j \rangle = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_i a_j \langle e_i, e_j \rangle =\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_i B_{i,j} a_j = a^T B a. $$
Thus, $B$ is positive-definite. On the other hand, the very same computation shows that any positive-definite matrix defines a scalar product.

Now we can translate your question into a question about matrices. Namely, if your conjecture was true, then we would have for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ that
$$ x^T A^T B A y = \langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle = x^T B y. $$
Thus, this is equivalent to
$$ A^T B A = B. $$
Meaning that every positive-definite matrix would be invariant under conjucation by unitary (wrt to the standard scalar product). So this tells us that we should play around a bit with positive-definite matrices and unitary matrices.

If I do not know whether something is true, I try to see what is going on for easy cases. Well, $n=1$ is trivial, so we should try $n=2$. The easiest (nontrivial) unitary is a permutation, so let's take $A(x,y) = (y,x)$ and the easiest (nontrivial) positive-definite for me is
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}. $$
Now we test it on easy vectors. Let $x\neq 0$, then we get
$$ \langle T(x,0), T (x,0) \rangle = \langle (0,x), (0,x) \rangle = 2 x^2 \neq x^2 = \langle (x,0), (x,0) \rangle. $$

This tells us that your conjecture is not true.

Of course, you can now go on and try to classify all the scalar product that do have this property. Using the permutation that swaps $e_1$ and $e_i$ and fixes all other $e_j$'s one readily checks that $B_{i,i} = B_{1,1}$. Furthermore, considering the orthogonal map that sends $e_i \mapsto e_k, e_k \mapsto -e_i$ and fixes the other coordinates for $i\neq k$, we get $B_{i.k}= -B_{i,k}$ and hence $B_{i,k}=0$. Thus, $B=c Id_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ for some $c>0$ (as $B$ is positive-definit) and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle = c(\cdot, \cdot)$ (where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the standard scalar product.

Answer (score -1):

Using identity $(u, v) = \frac{1}{4}(|u+v|^2 - |u-v|^2)$, first for $u = T(x)$ and $v = T(y)$, then for $u = x$ and $v = y$ we get:

$(T(x),T(y)) = \frac{1}{4}(|T(x)+T(y)|^2 - |T(x)-T(y)|^2) = \frac{1}{4}(|T(x+y)|^2 - |T(x-y)|^2) = \frac{1}{4}(|x+y|^2 - |x-y|^2) = (x,y)$

We used the fact that T is isometry (because it's an orthogonal operator), i.e. $|T(x)| = |x|$

Comment: That's not right: fixing the norm fixes the inner product. The question is asking about whether it works for any inner product.

Comment: Because A is orthogonal matrix, T will be orthogonal operator, and what I wrote follows

Comment: You cannot show the statement as it is not true. Take the inner product $\langle (x,y), (u,v) \rangle = xu + 2yv$ and $T(x,y) = (y,x)$. The operator $T$ is orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product, but not for the one I wrote above, as we have for $x\neq 0$ $$ \langle (x,0), (x,0)\rangle = x^2 \neq 2x^2 = \langle (0, x), (0, x) \rangle = \langle T(x,0), T(x,0) \rangle. $$

Comment: The whole point of this question is whether $T$ is orthogonal with respect to a new scalar product if we know $T$ is orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product. You are using $\vert T(x) \vert = \vert x \vert$ which you would know for the euclidean norm, but for the polarisation formalula to hold true, you need to take the norm induced by the new scalar product.